# Python 'not' operator

Tags: python, boolean, boolean-logic

```
x = 0

if not x:
    print(bool(x))
    print("Evaluated True")

else:
    print(bool(x))
    print("Evaluated False")
```

Output

```
False
Evaluated True
```

Why is the else block not  executed?
I think x = 0 is `False`, not x is `True`. Or do I misunderstand the boolean definition?

Comment: welcome  please format your code in code snippet

Comment: as you said, `not x` is indeed `True`, that's why the `if` is executed...

Comment: You are testing for not x, but then printing x and "true". You need to test for not x, print not x and "true". I think you just missed that testing x does not change its value. So testing not x but printing `bool(x) ` is kind of nonsensical

Answer (score 2):

You must print your if expression 'not x'. Then you see not x == not False == True.

```
x = 0

if not x:
    print(bool(not x))
    print("Evaluated True")

else:
    print(bool(not x))
    print("Evaluated False")
```

answer:

```
True
Evaluated True
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> x = 0
>>> if x:
...   print(bool(x), "Evaluated True")
... else:
...   print(bool(x),"Evaluated False")
... 
False Evaluated False
```

**Note:** The boolean value is True for all integers except 0

Answer (score 1):

When the expression inside the if statement is true the if block is executed. Since x is 0 then `not x` is true which means the if block will execute not the else block.

print(bool(x)) will print false since x is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Thus it as you say: `not x == True` so the if statement get executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
if not x
```

This is true, that's why the line following the if is executed. Ergo, the else is NOT executed. It would only be executed if the if statement would be false.

Answer (score 1):

The boolean value is true for all except 0. `not x == True` so it's evaluated `true`.

Answer (score 1):

```
False
Evaluated True
```

Your output is correct.
You got the boolean concept right(*x = 0 is False, not x is True*) but your implementation is wrong.

```
x = 0

if not x:
    print(bool(x))
    print("Evaluated True")
```

In your code:

`if not x` means `if (not x)==True` which is absolutely correct hence the if condition runs.

Using `if (some condition)` is sometimes tricky. Its also sometimes due to absence of parentheses.

You can achieve the desired output with this `if (not x)==False`.

Comment: Means the condition in the if statement must be 'True' to execute the if block right ?